# Create multiple objects from strong params array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where a user can upload multiple images.  I need the controller to create a `user_item_image` for each image that is uploaded.

A `user_item` has many `user_item_images`.

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "user_item_images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "picture"
  end
```

**form**

```
<%= form_for :user_item_image, url: user_item_user_item_images_path(@user_item) do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture, multiple: true %>
    <%= f.submit %>
```

**controller**

```
  def create
    @user_item = UserItem.find_by_id(params[:user_item_id]).user_item_images.create(user_item_image_params)
    redirect_to :back
  end

 private

  def user_item_image_params
    params.require(:user_item_image).permit({picture:[]})
  end
```

I'm not sure how to make the controller's create action.  What I have doesn't work.  The `user_item_image_params` looks like this

```
>>  user_item_image_params
=> {"picture"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f67d9b77d28 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160317-588761-mjk73n.JPG>, @original_filename="IMG_0313.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg",   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_item_image[picture][]\"; filename=\"IMG_0313.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f67d9b77d00 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160317-588761-edqw7.JPG>, @original_filename="IMG_0314.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_item_image[picture][]\"; filename=\"IMG_0314.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f67d9b77cd8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160317-588761-buatxk.JPG>, @original_filename="IMG_0315.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_item_image[picture][]\"; filename=\"IMG_0315.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}
```

**UPDATE**

I changed my controller to this:

```
  def create
    # raise 'foo'
    @user_item = UserItem.find_by_id(params[:user_item_id])
    user_item_image_params[:picture].each do |p|
      user_item_image = @user_item.user_item_images.build(picture: p)
      user_item_image.save
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

This seems to work, but I dunno does this seem too hacky?  Is there a better way?
Also doing it like this how can I create the logic on what to do if there is a validation failure?  Usually it's something like `if x.save...`.  I'm not sure if I should make it so nothing saves if one file is invalid or just have valid ones save and how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Have you tried `params.require(:user_item_image).permit(:picture)`?

Comment: @dan-klasson yes if I try that, I get a problem with strong params and `user_item_image_params` is just an empty hash.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the datatype. You have used `string` data type in your schema but passing an object that is not a string. I would suggest you to use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) gem. It would handle your attachments.

Still you do not want to use any gem then you need to store those pictures on any server then save the path in the database as a string.

Comment: I am already using carrierwave.  Are you saying that the controller create action should work the way I have it?